# How to logout GoogleAccountCredential in android?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, AUDIENCE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName("...@gmail.com");
```

So far so good, everything works.

```
credential.setSelectedAccountName("");
credential.setSelectedAccountName(null);
```

All endpoints including requests to methods that do not have a user object get broken. Error `bad username`. The only way I found to fix it is to create a `private HttpRequestInitializer nocredential;` to replace `credential`.

Is there a better way to reset `credential` to get a logout state like a `private HttpRequestInitializer nocredential;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! I just tried `credential = null;` that also works :)